# How to hook up Jenkins to Endevor?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, mainframe

I'm not DevOps, I only come from a .net background, but I've been asked how to hook up Jenkins to kick off jobs, listening to Endevor mainframe?

I only found [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/IBM+zOS+Connector) which talks about SCLM which as I understand is a competitor company.

Comment: Hi you can have a look at the: Integrating Jenkins Pipeline with CA Endevor Software Change Manager on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEKv5DIEtU4&t=7s

Answer (score 1):

Apart from your "[this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/IBM+zOS+Connector)", there is also [Compuware Source Code Download for Endevor, PDS, and ISPW Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Compuware+Source+Code+Download+for+Endevor%2C+PDS%2C+and+ISPW+Plugin). Some details about it (from the linked page):

> ... allows Jenkins users to download Endevor, PDS, or ISPW members from the mainframe to the PC. Source can then be accessed on the PC, for example, for SonarQube analysis and reporting.

So you may want to give "that" a try ...

PS: I'm assuming your question is about Endevor SCM, and not Endevor DB (that a completely different story, and a challenging one ...).